# Time stamp for pictures actually taken before being sent to recipient on iphone

Tags: iphone, messages, graphics, time

My boyfriend sent me a picture from his Iphone 6, I have an iphone 5.  I wanted to know if it was possible to find out when the picture was actually taken, not just sent to me or saved on my own iphone.  Is there any way to find this out?  I have used certain apps to find out with no luck.  They only show me when I saved the picture sent to my phone or when he sent the picture to me in a text.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://regex.info/exif.cgi)

Can show you some of the metadata/exif about an image. It should show you the date of when the picture was taken.